# bring window to front of another window titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I Have two window

window 1:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'black',
    url : 'Car.js'
});
```

window 2:

```
var menuWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    width : deviceWidth * 0.0000001,
    toogle : false,
});

win.open();
menuWindow.open();
```

In the first window that occupies the entire screen i need to lode a .js file like i do with "url: 'Car.js'". the second window is hiden and when i make swipe on the first window the second window must appear above the first window. how can I bring a window to front and keep the other window in background?

Answer (score 0):

@Manuel_Rodrigues We just need to add some properties to the "new window" can accomplish this (here is the example):

1.***win.js***

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});

//sliding animation
var slide_to_right = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    left: 0,
    duration: 200
});

//win swipe listener
win.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.direction == 'right'){         //swipe to right open the menuWindow
        //Alloy
        var menu_win = Alloy.createController('menu_window').getView();
        menu_win.setLeft('-100%');      //menuWindow will open with a sliding animation from left
        menu_win.open(slide_to_right); 

        /*
        //not Alloy
        var menuWin = require('/menu_window');    //path of menu_window.js
        var menuWindow = new menuWin();
        menuWindow.open(slide_to_right);
        */
    }
});
win.open();
```

2.***menu_window.js***

```
//Alloy
var menuWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width: '40%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    theme: 'Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar'    //backgroundColor set 'transparent' make the menuWindow seems suspend above the win-window, the 'theme' property just remove the window default tile navigation-bar in android  
});
menuWindow.open();

/*
//not Alloy
function menuWin(){
    var menuWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        width: '40%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        theme: 'Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar'
    });
    return menuWindow;
}

module.exports = menuWin;
*/
```

So, the key to accomplish what you want is set the ***backgroundColor*** and ***theme*** properties to the new window, in addition, define a ***open animation*** to change the window open system-default-animation. However, I do not recommend you apply this way, cause there's no need to define the **menu**(which you want show in the base window) as a window UI component, you just can define the menu as a **view** which would show after you do the swipe action. I think this will also work for you and better.

Hope these can help you! Good luck!